# ERROR:but still working of code:Index out of range

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python please help me to solve this..

```
list=[12,13,421,151,15]
x=int(input("Enter the number to remove that ele from list"))

for i in range(0,5):
    if(x==list[i]):
        list.pop(i)
        print(list)

else:
    print('ELEMENT NOT FOUND')
```

ERROR :

```
Enter the number to remove that ele from list13
[12, 421, 151, 15]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Data_Structure/Stack2.py", line 5, in <module>
    if(x==list[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If any of the answers did help you, so please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error only if the value is inside the list[]. 
Because when the value is found inside the list, you are popping it out of the list which then your list[] index will become 1 smaller.

What you can do is just do this:

```
list=[12,13,421,151,15]
x=int(input("Enter the number to remove that ele from list"))

list.remove(x)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you delete a certain value of the list but you keep checking the value in the index i (`list[i]`).

A side note.
Do not use `list` as a name for one of your variable. You would shadow a builtin python variable name. It can cause some very annoying bugs later on.

What you can do is or to break your loop after "poping" out the value.

```
my_list = [12, 13, 421, 151, 15]
x = int(input("Enter the number to remove that ele from list"))

for i in range(5):
    if x == my_list[i]:
        my_list.pop(i)
        print(my_list)
        break

else:
    print('ELEMENT NOT FOUND')
```

or just simply removing the value from the list.
using `remove`

```
my_list = [12, 13, 421, 151, 15]
x = int(input("Enter the number to remove that ele from list"))
my_list.remove(x)
```